# Is it possible to search buttons that contain certain aria-label text with screen readers?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

For example I have `<button aria-label="Play video">+</button>` on a page. How do I search with screen readers for a element containing "play video" on the page? Is there a better way?

I'm trying to understand if there's a way for screen readers to "jump" to a part of the page, ie search for an element.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! please provide what you've already tried or think about implementing but don't know exactly how to (in which case, explain the process). in addition, we'll need some more information about what it is that you're trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: @Grey Thank you, updated the description and hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to search an element by its text!

just press Insert+CTRL+F and type the text of an element which you want to find.